# Deploying Lambda Function with CDK Failing Due to Missing Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-cdk

```
new Function(this, "TestFunction", {
    handler: "TestFunction.handler",
    code: Code.asset(path.join(__dirname, "lambdas/")),
    runtime: Runtime.NodeJS810
});
```

When I try to deploy this to CodeDeploy, I get:

```
Parameters: [TestFunctionCodeS3Bucket, TestFunctionCodeS3VersionKey] must have values (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError;
```

When I check the CloudFormation generated, I can see the parameters:

```
TestFunctionCodeS3Bucket:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 bucket for asset "AppStack/TestFunction/Code"
TestFunctionCodeS3VersionKey:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 key for asset version "AppStack/TestFunction/Code"
```

My understanding is that `Code.asset` should bootstrap this process on its own. Is there a step I'm missing here?

Looking at the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/serverless_example.html), it states that you're suppose to create an `Amazon S3 bucket that contains the Lambda function code.` However, nowhere in the example do I see that being done explicitly. So I just assumed it was done implicitly.

Generated CFN:

```
Parameters:
  TestFunctionCodeS3BucketE8C956AE:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 bucket for asset "AppStack/TestFunction/Code"
  TestFunctionCodeS3VersionKey6B3F3155:
    Type: String
    Description: S3 key for asset version "AppStack/TestFunction/Code"
Resources:
  TestFunctionServiceRole6ABD93C7:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: AppStack/TestFunction/ServiceRole/Resource
  TestFunction22AD90FC:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: TestFunctionCodeS3BucketE8C956AE
        S3Key:
          Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - Fn::Select:
                  - 0
                  - Fn::Split:
                      - "||"
                      - Ref: TestFunctionCodeS3VersionKey6B3F3155
              - Fn::Select:
                  - 1
                  - Fn::Split:
                      - "||"
                      - Ref: TestFunctionCodeS3VersionKey6B3F3155
      Handler: TestFunction.handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - TestFunctionServiceRole6ABD93C7
          - Arn
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
    DependsOn:
      - TestFunctionServiceRole6ABD93C7
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: AppStack/TestFunction/Resource
      aws:asset:path: /Volumes/Unix/AMCC/src/AMCConsole/packages/infrastructure/lib/lambdas/mars
      aws:asset:property: Code
  CDKMetadata:
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Modules: aws-cdk=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/assets=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/assets-docker=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-codebuild=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-codecommit=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-api=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-cognito=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-ec2=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-ecr=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-events=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-iam=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-kms=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-lambda=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-route53=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-s3=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-s3-notifications=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-serverless=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-sns=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-sqs=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/cdk=0.22.0,@aws-cdk/cx-api=0.22.0,jsii-runtime=node.js/v11.12.0
```

Comment: Try to run `cdk bootstrap`  and change `NodeJS810` to `NODEJS_8_10`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use CDK version 0.22 for this specific project. `fromAsset` and `NODEJS_8_10 ` I believe are 1.0 >. I tried to bootstrap as well. The CloudFormation looks correct, which is why its confusing.

Comment: Can you share the complete cloudformation template?

Comment: I added it to the question : ).

Answer (score 0):

Hello Kris I had the same problem here's how I solved it :

- checked the manifest.json created in the output to get the key of the parameters (I extracted it with jq and created a config file from if)
- the S3 key required this format -> PATH/||YOUR_ASSET_KEY